# How can I conditionally sum given a latent indicator?

Tags: r, statistics, sum, conditional-statements, poisson

I have the following summation that I want to compute in R:

```
$\sum^K_{k=1} [(1-z_i) * log[y_i|\lambda_0] + z_i * log[y_i|\lambda_1]]$, where [y_i|\lambda_{1/2}] follows a Poisson(\lambda_{1/2}) distribution.
```

The latent indicator variable z_i is equal to either 0 or 1, which is provided in the vector z.

I currently have this code in my R script:

```
sum(dpois(y,lambda0,log=TRUE)[z==0]+dpois(y,lambda1,log=TRUE)[z==1])
```

I am receiving the following error,

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

which I do not believe is really my issue in this case. I just do not know how to condition my summation. I am relatively new to R and would really appreciate your help.

Comment: It seems likely that the number of elements of z that are equal to 0 is different to the number of elements of z that are equal to 1. You are therefore trying to add together vectors of different lengths.Attempting that will produce the error you report. However, since you just want a sum of all the elements of both vectors, you don't need to add them inside the sum function. You should get the answer you are looking for by simply replacing the `+` between your `dpois` arguments with a comma.

Comment: @AllanCameron I see what you are saying. Yes, the number of elements in z equal to 0 differ from those equal to 1. I switched the comma and the plus, and I obtained an answer. Thank you for that! However, I am still getting the same warning, oddly. Is this a reason for concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `y` and `z` are of equal length, then you can try the code below, and I believe it is mathematically equivalent to your objective

```
sum(dpois(y,lambda0,log=TRUE)*(1-z)+dpois(y,lambda1,log=TRUE)*z)
```

Comment: I attempted both your solution and the suggestion provided by @Allan Cameron in the comments. They work and provided roughly the same solution. Since y and z are of equal length, this is perfect. I am curious as to why I had to change my plus to a comma in my original approach, but using a plus in your solution managed just fine. Any insights there? Also, your solution will work for any values of z, not just 1 and 0, which was going to be my next question, so this really helped! However, I am still getting the same error. Should I just ignore the error?

Comment: @Edison In my solution, if you have only `0` and `1` in `z`, that `0` elements in `z` will contribute nothing to the sum. Likewise, for `1-z`, those positions with `1`s in `z` will contribute nothing. Since `0` and `1` positions are exclusive, so you can use `1-z` and `z` as masks

Comment: Got it- thanks for your help! Really appreciate it.